# Need to press the power button twice for Ubuntu 15.04 to boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, power-management, 15.04

I have a dual boot set up (Windows 7/Ubuntu 15.04).

I've recently upgraded from 14.04 LTS to 15.04 and since then, I have to press the power button twice.

The first time it goes to GRUB without any issues, then when I choose to boot Ubuntu it starts loading it and does it successfully.
But then, the computer shuts down, and I have to press the power button again. But this time it finishes loading Ubuntu, it doesn't load GRUB again.

It doesn't happen with Windows - the computer just boot Windows without any issues.

Comment: At what point (before login, after) or after how long does the pc shuts down (1 minute or more?) Isn't it an **hibernation** instead of a shutdown ? Is there any *LED* blinking after it has "shut down" ?

Comment: It's right after the loading screen. The screen then goes black and the pc shut's down. At that point I have to press the button again and ubuntu starts normal

Comment: Are you sure it shuts down ? Is it not only the screen that goes black ? I had that issue with a PC.

Comment: it could be hibernation, I'm not sure because the LED laptop goes off when it's in hibernation